# How to implement ScrollView for my layout containing both text, image and ListView

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout, android-xml, android-scrollview

I'm trying to add a ScrollView to my layout that is containing various TextViews, a ImageView and a ListView. The reason to why I want to be able to scroll is because all the text and the image takes up nearly all the space and leaves to little for the ListView.

I have no idea on how to implement this tough.
Heres my XML code for the layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pubInfoImg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pubInfoWelcome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pubInfoTapsNo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:padding="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.7dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pubInfoAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pubInfoUrl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pubInfoOpenhours"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/tapsListview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#BABABA"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0.0sp"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

if u want to set the imageview or textview at the end of list then u can use ListView.addFooterView(footerView); it will add the view in foooter of listview in android